# Getting rails console to work with multiple Gemfiles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, bundler

We are currently migrating from Rails 4 to 5, and have two Gemfiles (similar to how GitHub [did it](https://github.blog/2018-09-28-upgrading-github-from-rails-3-2-to-5-2/)), `Gemfile` (Rails 4) and `Gemfile_5` (Rails 5).

The following commands work as expected:

```
bundle exec rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.11.12 LTS application starting in development on http://localhost:3000

BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile_5 bundle exec rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 5.0.7.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:8000
```

```
bundle exec rspec spec/...
# runs specs using Rails 4 gemset

BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile_5 bundle exec rspec spec/...
# runs specs using Rails 5 gemset
```

```
bundle exec rails --version
Rails 4.2.11

BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile_5 bundle exec rails --version
Rails 5.0.7.1
```

And yet, when trying to run `console` or `runner`, it'll only use the Rails 4 gemset:

```
BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile_5 bundle exec rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.11.12 LTS)
```

```
BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile_5 bundle exec rails r "puts Rails.version"
4.2.11
```

I've tried restarting Spring, but that hasn't had any effect. What am I missing here?

Comment: For now, I'm adding a `byebug` to a spec as a way to get a Rails 5 console, but I'd like a less convoluted manner of getting in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick was to fully disable Spring, rather than just restart it:

```
DISABLE_SPRING=1 BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile_5 bundle exec rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.7.1)
```